# Simple parse not printing out date in string

Tags: perl

I'm not sure why my parse isn't working on this string.  I got it to work by putting the `?` after the `.*`, but I don't understand why the 1st parse isn't working.  Here is the string and the 1st and 2nd parses.

```
my $string = "/usr/local/bin/python3.9 -u /usr/local/bin/scripts/master_program.py 4002 daily true 20230421";
my $pythonpgm = "master_program.py";
my ($midmark1) = $string =~ /.*$pythonpgm \d+ .*(\d+).*/;
my ($midmark2) = $string =~ /.*$pythonpgm \d+ .*?(\d+).*/;

print "\nmidmark1 =>  $midmark1\n";
print "\nmidmark2 =>  $midmark2\n\n";
```

This is the printout:

```
midmark1 =>  1

midmark2 =>  20230421
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.*` matches everything it can. It would match up until the end of the string, but then the `\d+` wouldn't match.

```
...master_program.py 4002 daily true 20230421
\_/\_______________/|\__/|\_________________/         XXX Wrong
 |         |        | |  |        |          X
 |         |        |  \  \       |          |
 .*    $pythonpgm  [ ] \d+ [ ]    .*       (\d+) .*
```

So it gives up one character to allow `\d+` to match.

```
...master_program.py 4002 daily true 20230421
\_/\_______________/|\__/|\________________/||
 |         |        | |  |        |         | \
 |         |        |  \  \       |         |  \
 .*    $pythonpgm  [ ] \d+ [ ]    .*      (\d+) .*
```

I'd use

```perl
/ \Q$pythonpgm\E [ ] \d+ [ ] .* [ ] (\d+) \z /xs
```

or just

```perl
/ \Q$pythonpgm\E [ ] .* [ ] (\d+) \z /xs
```

The space before the date acts as an anchor, forcing `.*` to backtrack further.

Answer (score 0):

> I got it to work by putting the ? after the .*, but I don't
> understand why

you are confronted with "greediness"

`*` is a greedy quantifier, `*?` non-greedy

You'll find many examples and detailed explanation in the docs:

--> https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Quantifiers

> By default, a quantified subpattern is "greedy", that is, it will
> match as many times as possible (given a particular starting location)
> while still allowing the rest of the pattern to match. If you want it
> to match the minimum number of times possible, follow the quantifier
> with a "?". Note that the meanings don't change, just the
> "greediness":

--> https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Matching-repetitions

> Quantifiers that grab as much of the string as possible are called maximal match or greedy quantifiers.

> Sometimes greed is not good. At times, we would like quantifiers to
> match a minimal piece of string, rather than a maximal piece. For this
> purpose, Larry Wall created the minimal match or non-greedy
> quantifiers ??, *?, +?, and {}?. These are the usual quantifiers with
> a '?' appended to them.